# When is の at the end of the sentence used as a suggestion/request?

Tags: particle-の

あああ　羨ましい。
こいつ　クリスマスは恋人とショーに見に行くんだって

To which she answers

そうそう そんなにひがまないの
もしかして　クリスマスまでに　素敵な恋人ができるかもしれないし

My understanding from context is that she's saying そんなにひがまないの akin to "don't be so jealous"

And then how he may get a lover for Christmas. Why is the   の particle used here instead of ないで?

Comment: As for the difference from ひがまないで, I feel の tends to sound slightly more childish/girly, and carries a sense of obligation/generalization. It's typically used when a mom says "Don't do ～" or "You should ～ (in a case like this)" to her child.